# Scala Visbility rules question over package scope trait with example taken from cats internal

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

In the cats library we have in the package cats.instances

in function.class

```
trait FunctionInstances extends cats.kernel.instances.FunctionInstances with Function0Instances with Function1Instances

....
....
....

sealed private[instances] trait Function1Instances extends Function1Instances0 {
  implicit def catsStdContravariantMonoidalForFunction1[R: Monoid]: ContravariantMonoidal[* => R] =
    new ContravariantMonoidal[* => R] {
      def unit: Unit => R = Function.const(Monoid[R].empty)
      def contramap[A, B](fa: A => R)(f: B => A): B => R =
        fa.compose(f)
      def product[A, B](fa: A => R, fb: B => R): ((A, B)) => R = {
        case (a, b) => Monoid[R].combine(fa(a), fb(b))
      }
    }

  implicit def catsStdMonadForFunction1[T1]: Monad[T1 => *] =
    new Monad[T1 => *] {
      def pure[R](r: R): T1 => R = _ => r

      def flatMap[R1, R2](fa: T1 => R1)(f: R1 => T1 => R2): T1 => R2 =
        t => f(fa(t))(t)

      override def map[R1, R2](fa: T1 => R1)(f: R1 => R2): T1 => R2 =
        f.compose(fa)
```

and we can see

`sealed private[instances] trait Function1Instances`  which makes its member only visible in the package Instance

In the Package Object Instances in the package cats, we have:

```
package object instances {

.......

.......


object function extends FunctionInstances with FunctionInstancesBinCompat0

.......

}
```

Then in the Invariant.class in cats package, we have:

```
object Invariant extends ScalaVersionSpecificInvariantInstances with InvariantInstances0 {
....
....

implicit def catsMonadForFunction1[I]: Monad[I => *] = cats.instances.function.catsStdMonadForFunction1[I]

....
```

I wonder how `catsStdMonadForFunction1[I]` is visible to Invariant. I thought could only be visble from **package instances** including the associated **package object instances**.

So the object `function` can see and call `catsStdMonadForFunction1[I]` because it implements the trait and the visibility is scope to **package instances** . But for I don't understand why `Invariant` can see that method.

Can someone explain that visbility rule applied here ?

Comment: Because the object `function` is public. So anyone can access all the fields of such object.

Comment: Really ? That’s quite easy to break visibility then ? U implement an object and boom all the rules are gone ! I don’t see any benefit of the protection then. Why they did put some private stuff there, what did it prevent ?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean the **trait** is private, the **object** is not. They want the values provided by the trait to be public and accessible through and import, but they do not want the trait itself to be public, since it's an implementation detail that they may change.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez isn't ```sealed private[instances] trait Function1Instances``` a private trait ? scope to visibility in the instance package only ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ```but they do not want the trait itself to be public, since it's an implementation detail that they may change``` That make sense now.

Comment: You should post your full response so i can +1 u